# Filtrar edades django

Tags: django, django-models

Buenas tardes amigos, estoy creando una app en Django 1.10 y tengo un modelo donde se almacenanaran los datos basicos de las personas, este modelo incluye un campo fechaNaciento, en este modelo cree un metodo el cual me calcula la edad de las personas.

```
class Beneficiario(models.Model):
    numeroDocumento = models.IntegerField()
    fechaNacimiento = models.DateField(null=True)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Sexo)


    def getEdad(self):
        return int((datetime.now().date() - self.fechaNacimiento).days / 365.25)
```

El problema que tengo es que necesito realizar una consulta donde me filtre por rango de edad, es decir un rango seria los de 0 a 20, otro de 21 a 40, etc. Lo que he leido en la documentación es que no se puede hacer la consulta con el metodo que cree. ¿De que otra forma puedo hacer esta consulta?

De antemano agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1):

de 0 a 20

```
.filter(fechaNacimiento__range=["1997-01-01", "2017-12-31"])
```

21 a 40

```
.filter(fechaNacimiento__range=["1977-01-01", "1996-12-31"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Es cierto, no se puede hacer un filtro sobre métodos, ya que muchas de las cosas que nosotros creamos no las entiende la API que se conecta a la base de datos, por lo cual hay que trabajar con lo que la API nos ofrece.

Investigando un poco tu pregunta, creo que puedo llegar a solucionarla con el uso de anotaciones, de esta forma:

```
from django.db import models
queryset = Beneficiario.objects.annotate(edad=
    models.ExpressionWrapper(
        datetime.now().date() - models.F('fechaNacimiento') + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    , output_field=models.DurationField())
)
```

De esta forma ya tienes en `queryset` las edades de cada beneficiario, puedes comprobarlo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
>>> queryset[0].edad
datetime.timedelta(632, 28172)  # son datos inventados
```

Lo que ves aquí, es el delta de el tiempo transcurrido desde el nacimiento hasta el día de hoy. Solo queda filtrar.

Como dijiste en tu pregunta, quieres hacerlo por rangos, y como tienes los rangos definidos no es mas que hacer esto.

Como estas trabajando con delta de tiempo, no necesitas tener fechas exactas si no algo un poco mas relativo, es decir, saber que de lunes a lunes hay 8 días, por lo tanto, siguiendo con esa idea es valido decir que:

```
RANGE_0_TO_20 = (
    datetime.date.today() - datetime.date.today(),
    datetime.date(year=2017, month=1, day=2) - datetime.date(year=1997, month=1, day=1)
)
```

Aquí puse esa fecha de ejemplo, pero puedes poner cualquier fecha, lo importante es que hayan 7.300 días de diferencia para los 20 años, por lo que no tendrás nada harcodeado (en la otra respuesta de @jorge cuando las personas de 20 años cumplan 40 años, seguirán saliendo en la consulta de las personas que tienen 20 años, por lo que está harcodeado, acá será dinámico).

Añado el de 40 años, y puedes añadir cuantos mas quieras:

```
RANGE_20_TO_40 = (
    datetime.date(year=2017, month=1, day=2) - datetime.date(year=1997, month=1, day=1),
    datetime.date(year=2017, month=1, day=2) - datetime.date(year=1987, month=1, day=1)
)
```

Teniendo los rangos ya establecidos, yo haría un `manager` con un `queryset` para evitar repetirme, pero por motivos, que esa no es la pregunta, pasarías a hacer el filtro de la siguiente manera:

```
queryset.filter(edad__range=RANGE_0_TO_20)
queryset.filter(edad__range=RANGE_20_TO_40)
```

Con esto, espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda, pregunta :D